# JavaScript checking if something is unique in an array

Tags: javascript

I've been searching around SO and google but I'm not sure how to go about what I'm doing. I'm creating my own little app that uses ajax and Yahoo API to bring back RSS feed information and display it to the page, it brings back title, description, thumbnail and GUID.
The issue at hand is data returned in the array with an image is duplicated so my idea is "I'll check guids and if they aren't unique remove one" but what I've tried isn't working. Any advice is appreciated!

This is how I'm getting my data, converting xml into JSON which will contain properties "title, description, pubdate, thumbnail & guid"

```
function getData() {
    return $.getJSON("giant yahoo api url" + "%22&format=json&callback=?",
        function(data) {
        }
   );
```

Duplicate handling

```
handlebars.registerHelper("removeDuplicate", function(results) {
    var a = results;
    var b = results.guid;
    var i = 2;

    foreach(b in a) {
        if( b.count != 1) {
            b--;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add some example data.

Comment: I've added how I get the data, since the data is different for each object in the Array I hope this is good enough? since I'm not writing out the array I can only say that looking in chrome dev tools they are all String data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the duplicate issue I was having I've written a handlebars helper as I was doing before but with a couple of tweaks it now works as intended and returns only the [0] item if the item is in an array!

```
handlebars.registerHelper("rssFeed", function(results) {
    var a = results;        

    if(Array.isArray(a)) {
        return a[0];
    }
    else {
        return a;
    }       
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can filter like below:

```
var uniques = [];    

results.forEach(function(result)) {
    var control = true;
    uniques.forEach(function(single) {
       if(single.guid == result.guid) control = false;
       if(control) uniques.push(result);
    })
}
```

Comment: What does push do in this case ?

Comment: push to uniques array from results array current object when not equal any record in uniques

Answer (score -1):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce`, quick (sloppy) example:

```
handlebars.registerHelper("removeDuplicate", function(results) {
  return results.reduce(function(arr, item) {
    var unique = true;
    arr.forEach(function(i) {
      if (i.guid === item.guid) unique = false;
    });
    if (!unique) return arr;
    arr.push(item);
    return arr;
  }, []);
});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote it so I'm not sure. I'm a bit apprehensive to try this as I'm not sure what the "push" keyword does

Comment: Reduce passes in an empty array. If it's not a duplicate, push the item to the reduced array and then return it, otherwise just return the reduced array without the duplicate value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Okay I'll have a play around and see if I can get something like this to work :)